# Adding sub header if content exceeds page in itext pdf

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, itext

See below screenshots of itext pdf created using java and jsp.
[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzgdy.png)

[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCiiz.png)

Now I want the headings CBC (Haemogram) and headings
Investigation, Result, Units, Biological Reference Interval on second page. The condition is that these headings to be added only if the content goes to second page and not if it only requires one page. How can I do this using itext pdf and java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using iText PdfPTable for this. Add the first cell as a header to this table and then enable it as the table's header using the below.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.addCell(addColumnHeader()); //add header labels here
table.setHeaderRows(1); //set first row as header of table
```

This way, if your table is split upon reaching the next page, the header will be automatically rendered as the first row on the next page